# How to write the value of a general-purpose 64 bit register into MMX?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, visual-c++-2010, mmx

I'm working with x64 assembly  and Visual C++ 2010/MASM is telling me that the instruction

`movq mm0, rax`

contains "invalid instruction operands".

Is this really illegal, or could it be a bug?
How does one perform this procedure without using the instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, or you didn't specify 64 bit mode or MMX extensions.
`movq mm0, rax` is a valid instruction with machine code `48 0F 6E C0`.
See the intel instruction set reference. If all else fails, you can include the machine code as data bytes.

That said, MMX is obsolete (especially since in 64 bit mode you by default have SSE2). Make sure you really want to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't specify [...] MMX extensions" ?

Comment: I don't know `masm` but maybe it needs an option or directive to enable `mmx` code. Here you go, [msdn says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e9yd754.aspx) you have to use `.mmx` directive.